# Is there a way to simplify working with nesting data in spark-sql?

Tags: arrays, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm working with spark-sql (with Scala) and I found out that there are so many limits when I want to manipulate array data inside a Dataframe for doing something more, without passing to RDD API and reconstruct the schema to come back to spark-sql Dataframe abstraction.

An example of my use case is: "given a nested structure, not just explode the records, but also merge and solve conflicts between records inside the array".

For example, consider a customer with the array of his orders, considering that orders could be ovelapped and for a customer could have more than one order with the same id: I want that in the exploding phase orders conflict between overlapped data will be solved.

Actually I can do that with rdd, but my code seems so tricky and I would like to do that without go at rdd level. Is there a way or a library that extends spark-sql for write clean code and do operation with arrays in a linear mode?

Another use case could be "I want to explode just the array that is a leaf in my nested Dataframe".

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: either use UDF or higher-order functions (transform/filter/aggregate)

Comment: Could help in the definition of schema, but I still remain to row level. And in this case how i could obtain the leaf array?

Comment: @mck in the meantime, thank you very much. I have compressed a lot my code with your advice.

Comment: Can you include an example input schema and output schema just for clarity?

Comment: For example you have an array of orders with inside two column that represents the product type and each record have a value for just one of this two fields